# I can not update UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary in a SPFieldMultiLineText field

Tags: sharepoint

I'm creating a custom list template by code for a site based on SharePoint 2010.
I added a field for description that should allow users entering more than 255 characters.
For that reason I'm trying to set UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary to "true" but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
SPFieldMultiLineText descField = tlistProdDest.Fields["Descripción"] as SPFieldMultiLineText;
descField.UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary = true;
descField.Update(true);
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Value changes to "true" when is set but, when Update() is executed, it returns to "fase".

Any idea?